# Interpretation of an integer division - C code

Tags: c, integer-division

I have the following C code:

```
int count = 0; // relative time
int T1 = 20; // period 1 in ms
int T2 = 50; // period 2 in ms
int T3 = 80; // period 3 in ms
   while (1) {
      if (count%T1 == 0) function1();
      if (count%T2 == 0) function2();
      if (count%T3 == 0) function3();
      count++;
      if (count == T1*T2*T3) count = 0;
      delay(1); // wait for 1 ms
   }
```

I'd like to know the reason for which there is the integer division count%T1==0 instead of count==T1. Maybe it takes into account the fact that the period T1 may not be an integer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code you posted, it looks like that:

- `function1` will be called **every** 20ms
- `function2` will be called **every** 50ms
- `function3` will be called **every** 80ms
- The counter resets **at** 80 seconds (20*50*80ms).

The keyword here is **every**.

Let's take `function1` trigger as example.

If you write `count == T1`, `function1` will only get executed once before a reset, when `count` is equal to **20**.

If you want to run `function1` **every** 20ms, you would expect it to execute at 20ms, 40ms, 60ms, and so on.

To translate this concept into code, you check if the counter is divisible by **20** via the modulo operator, hence the `count % T1` expression.

Same concept applies to `T2` and `T3` checks.

Comment: Hi @MatteoPasini can I use the condition count==T1 if I replace count=T1*T2*T3 with count=max(T1, T2, T3)?